# Passing Compass Points to PHP

Tags: compass-geolocation, point

I created a circle using paint (Circle.jpg) and placed 4 numbers for now around it representing North (360) East(90) West(270) and South(180). I am trying to pass to PHP what number I click on. Can not get it to work or can I find anything close to what I am trying to do. Opening an HTML link works but not what I need. Below code does produce a circle when clicked around selection. Below is code just for East(90). I have tried also adding value="90", does not make a difference. Thanks in advance for help.

```
<body>
<body bgcolor="#0080C0">
<img usemap="#shapes" src="images/Circle.jpg" alt="">
<map name="shapes" id="shapes">
  <area shape="circle" coords="158,76,10" href="#" bearing="90" alt="90" </area> 
<?php
$StateOrBearing = $_POST['bearing'];
echo $StateOrBearing;
?>
```

Comment: Did you just make the HTML attribute `bearing` up...?

Comment: trying to add the value of 90 to the variable bearing so that I can pass to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update your HREFs with appropriate parameter information.

```
<area shape="circle" coords="158,76,10" href="handler.php?location=90" />
```

If you need very fine granularity, you could also pass pixel coordinates in Javascript or use the now-antiquated server side image map, but that's a different can of worms.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I cant seem to get it to work. I can not echo $StateOrBearing with any info. I have created a separate file handler.php and tried it that way with no luck. Ihave used _Get and _Post also.

Comment: the href looks like this: 'file.php?bearing=90' ?  Note that it will be in $_GET, as it is not a post.

Comment: Here is what I have and unable to echo any information: href='handler.php?bearing=90' and in handler.php <?php
$StateOrBearing = $_GET['bearing'];
echo "Test: $StateOrBering"; ?>

Comment: You know you mispelled $StateOrBearing the 2nd time you used it, right?  You can always just test the GET properties irrespective of the image map by just hitting the URL with a properly formated query string:  http://server/handler.php?bearing=90 .  This way you can solve one potential problem at a time.

Comment: I was using ctr F5 to refresh the page after changes. I should have learned my lesson, that does not always work. href="handler.php?bearing=90" works perfect and is picked up with $_GET. I was trying to stay on the same web page and not switch to another, by replacing handler.php with the name of the page you are currently on it will refresh itself and stay there. I am controlling an external device so I don't need to change pages. Thanks John for your help and patience.

Comment: I tried but it tells me I am worthless and I have no reputation since I am a newbie, POS..... :~(

Comment: It was a joke, but you should mark questions as answered (the checkbox) if they are.

Comment: I know it was.... Thanks again for helping me create one of my best programs I have ever written.